# .NET 6.0 missing when creating a ASP.NET MVC Application in visual basic

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I'd like to create a MVC web app using ASP.NET and visual basic.
So, in Visual Studio, i've selected the corresponding template project :
[image]

In the next screen, why .NET 6.0 is missing (considering that if I select C# project template, .NET 6.0 is selectable) ?
[image]

EDIT:
I used Visual Studio Community 2022 up to date.
Here are the choices that i had when filtered to VB and Web project type:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version are you using? .NET 6 is only supported in VS 2022.

Another thing: You selected (.NET Framework) project. You have to select (Core)

Comment: I edited the question providing these infos

Comment: It seems that you cannot create a MVC template using VB. It accepts only C# and F#. More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new-sdk-templates

Comment: It seems indeed. And it was confirmed here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8674
BUT there is a template: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ModernVBNET.Vazor

Comment: Glad to see your problem solved, you can post your conclusion as answer and  click '✔' to mark it as the accepted answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.